# I need to check a specific range to find the last cell that has values, then paste values on the next cell down

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for assistance on a function. I want to check a specific range(F12:F34), find the last cell in that range that has values, then paste another set of values (already copied and waiting) in the next cell below. Basically this will fill this range throughout the day. Each row in the range is a duration at a job site. F column is the stop time of the assigned job. I was able to do this with a lot of IF's and Else IF's but I was hoping there would be a much more elegant (and shorter) code that could be written. Hope this explains what I'm trying accomplish.
Here is a link the sheet to see what it looks like:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/188fYdI50uJ-3Qpy-GzP4l0xgoJlgm_QegWmVCgarU-Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks that you are looking that someone write a script for you but that is off-topic on this site. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can get last row by reading all the values in column and then looping for blank in the cells. If you think that you can get blanks inbetween then you will have loop in reverse order. ie: `for(var i=rangeValues.length-1;i>=0;i--)`. Well, you may also come across situations where last row of spreadsheet will be filled with some data. In such cases inorder for the program to continue running you can insert a row and then return its position.

```
function nextFreeRow(){
  var rangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('foo').getRange('F:F').getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rangeValues.length;i++){
    if(rangeValues[i][0].toString() == "") return i+1;
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('foo').insertRowAfter(rangeValues.length);
  return rangeValues.length+1;
}
```